# Bind type variables in a GHCI session

Tags: haskell, ghci

Let's take `fmap . const` as a simple example where I try to understand what it does:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
const :: a -> b -> a
```

The fist thing I notice is that `a`, `b` are ambiguous when I try to understand `fmap . const`. The use of two or more related signatures together is what I mean by "`GHCI` session".

Here's example of what would help me understand things better:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
const :: c -> d -> c
fmap . const :: Functor g => h -> g i -> g h
```

Let's bind `g = f` and reduce `g`:

```
fmap . const :: Functor f => h -> f i -> f h
```

Pick `h :: h` as a least-confusing variable name for the pointful version:

```
\h -> fmap (const h) :: Functor f => h -> f i -> f h
```

Let's bind `h = c` and reduce `h`:

```
\c -> fmap (const c) :: Functor f => c -> f i -> f c
```

Now, it is much easier to see that `c` in `f c` came from first argument to `const`. I also see that `i` and `a` are free since I did not need to "operate" on them.

Questions:

- Is there a way to prevent letters being re-used in a `GHCI` session?
- Is there a way to bind and reduce type variables in a `GHCI` session?
- Finally, I suspect there is an easier way to do the equivalent thought process.

Comment: You cannot control which tyvar names the compiler chooses. To "bind and reduce" a type variable doesn't even make sense to me. (`a` and `b` are not ambiguous in `fmap . const` because they don't appear in its type at all). Finally, I'm not sure what the thought process here is - it seems like you're just asking GHCi for the type of an expression.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you are having trouble with the same type variable names being reused in different signatures? Different signatures have different scopes, so the type variables are completely unrelated to each other. When you construct an expression by applying other expressions, you might have to do capture avoiding substitution to find the correct type (if you're looking for that), but this is performed automatically by GHCi (for example, `:t fmap . const` will do this). I am also not sure what you mean by "bind and reduce" in this context.

Comment: Possibly another way to solve this problem would be to produce proof that type `:t fmap.const` is indeed what GHCI claims to be given types of `fmap` and `const`.

Comment: @sevo The result of `:t fmap . const` is a proof of its own result. That is, if the compiler gives an expression a type, then that is the type of that expression. If this wasn't the case, then what's the point of static type checking? I think what you want is a step-by-step explanation of how the compiler decides what the type should be.

Answer (score 0):

The type variables in signatures are actually bound by an implicit universal quantifier. There is a language extension to make it explicit, check that this compiles :

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

fmapPrime :: forall a b f. Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmapPrime = fmap

constPrime :: forall a b. a -> b -> a
constPrime = const

fmapConst :: forall a b f. Functor f => b -> f a -> f b
fmapConst = fmap . const
```

So you cannot say that the type variables variables are "reused" : they are not free.